# How to get the 'Width', when set 'HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"'?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, width, stretch

I had booked a `Grid` with `HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"`

And now, I want to know what is its `Width` ?

*I want to do this by C # at runtime.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It would be nice to edit your question and add the code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have the following grid:

```
<Grid Name="gvDummyContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

An you want to get the height and width of it. You can do it like this:

```
double actualWidth = gvDummyContent.ActualWidth;
double actualHeight = gvDummyContent.ActualHeight;
```

Be sure that you are calling these properties after the controls are loaded.